# Haskell Currying

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

For the past two hours I have been reading about currying in Haskell and all the resources present how the functions with multiple parameters actually return other functions, but not how their definitions looks like, so this is what the question is about.

Let us define the function:

```
myFunc :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
myFunc x y = x * 2 + x * y
```

`:t (myFunc 2)` prints `Num a => a -> a`, i.e. a function that takes a number and also outputs a number. However, what does the definition of the function returned by `(myFunc 2)` look like? Does the compiler substitute `x` in the definition and the new function becomes something like `myFunc' y = 2 * 2 + 2 * y`?

How does recursion handle currying? If I define the function

```
replicate' :: (Integral i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]
replicate' n x
    | n <= 0    = []
    | otherwise = x : replicate' (n - 1) x
```

, what is the function returned by `(replicate' 3)` in the context `(replicate 3) 'a'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `replicate'` defined in explicitly curried form:

```
replicate' :: (Integral i, Ord i) => i -> (a -> [a])
replicate' n
   | n <= 0     = const []
   | otherwise  = \x -> x : replicate' (n - 1) x
```

So then, `replicate' 3` evaluates to the expression

```
    if 3 <= 0 then const []
              else \x -> x : replicate' 2 x
```

which is just

```
  \x -> x : replicate' 2 x
```

If it's only defined with “implicit currying”, then the compiler may or may not pull out the `n <= 0` condition out of the `x` binding, so in fact you may merely end up with

```
    \x -> if 3 <= 0 then const []
                    else \x -> x : replicate' 2 x
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `\x -> x : replicate' 2 x` means? Also, does the compiler treat `myFunc` as I guessed?

Comment: Um, you do know how lambda functions work, right? Otherwise, this would be a good time to read up on them, they're hugely important.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are mixing up two different things

- currying
- partial function application

the first one is

```
                      ------currying-----> 
       f :: (a,b) -> c                      f' :: a -> b -> c
                      <----uncurrying-----
```

transforming a function that takes a **tuple** of arguments which means one argument of two things combined - into a function that takes one argument and produces a function!

If you are familiar with linear algebra this is very much alike viewing a bi-linear function as a linear function that produces another linear function.

Whereas partial function application is just a consequence of explicit parenthization.

```
f :: a -> b -> c
```

is really

```
f :: a -> (b -> c)
```

at least in the haskell way of defining functions.

Comment: Are you sure? According to Wikipedia, "currying is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument", and according to (https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application), partial function application is when I create a function, for example `func = replicate 3`, which only gives `replicate` a single argument. Calling `func var` will replicate var three times.

Comment: @RazvanMeriniuc what part of my answer do you disagree on - based on the wikipedia article you are quoting?

Comment: Currying does not only translate tuples, but also multiple arguments. Your second example is also currying and partial function application appears in the context I've presented before.

Comment: no in haskell the only way to have multiple arguments is having tuples, all functions with more than one argument is technically a function returning a function.